# osx file permission wrong user

Tags: macos, permissions

I'm a bit lost on this whole permission thing.

In the console when type `$ whoami` I get my username, which is also the administrator. So far so good.

When I then try to create a file `$ touch test.js` I get permission denied.

The parent folder belongs to the group 'staff' (`$ lg -ls`).

My goal is not to use `$ sudo` all  the time.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: what's the full path where you're working? You could be hitting SIP.

Comment: I'm in my dropbox directory

Comment: Dropbox folders should belong to you. Staff & everyone is read only.

Comment: Yes but that is exactly what I'm confused about. It should belong to me. How come I cannot create files in a folder that should belong to me? Does that mean, that my username isn't a member of `staff`?

Comment: 'staff' is the sudoers list… which is why it's working with sudo. idk why they're not being set up with you as owner, though.

Comment: with `$ dscacheutil -q group -a name staff`and `$dscacheutil -q group -a name admin`, root and myusername are listed. Is this expected?

Comment: Sorry, I've no clue. Closest I ever get to that is using BatChmod